# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when linking to css

Tags: css, html, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have two files in my root directory, `articles.php` and `article-output.php` which link to the same header file. `articles.php` renders correctly while `article-output.php` fails with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on all my `css` links.

I have pinpointed that the issue is likely that in my `.htaccess` file I use **articles/title   article-output.php?id=xyz** which makes the browser think it is a subdirectory (**localhost/articles/title**) and therefore my css links need `../css/style.css` instead of just  `css/style.css`.

Is there a way around this issue that I haven't come across? Can I put something in `.htaccess` to indicate the file is not physically in a subdirectory?

I tried linking with absolute path but then the browser was looking for **localhost/articles/localhost/css/styles.css**

Many thanks.

Comment: You Can View this link maybe help you to solve problem https://really-simple-ssl.com/forums/topic/err_too_many_redirects-when-htacess-edited/

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I'm after, but a good read.

Answer (score 0):

Use **HTTP://** to avoid doubling up on **localhost/** for the absolute path.